# Errors in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

When given the following function:

```
n=0
a=1
while a>0:
    n=n+1
    print n
    a=(1.0+2.0**(-n))-1.0
```

Python will stop at n=53 (meaning a=0, in this case). How come this happens? Theoretically, it should never stop. I'm assuming this has to do with python's aproximation errors, but is it "explainable"?

Comment: There are 53 bits of precision available for a Python float

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html